# Connecting WordPress with Asp.net backend

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wordpress, asp.net-web-api

I am good at building backend code in .net. I don't have enough knowledge of front end technologies. So I am thinking of building my website frontend in WordPress and backend in .net. I have some questions related to this.

1. Can this be done?
2. Is there any better alternative for building front end without much learning curve involved?
3. If I cannot link my backend with WordPress then is the WordPress safe and secure to build the e-commerce websites?